# Not able to create List of String object in java12

Tags: java, java-12

```
List<Object> al = Arrays.asList("ABC", "XYZ");
```

This code works fine in Java11 but when I try this in Java12, it gives an error.

Any hint of what I am missing?

Thanks for the help.

minimal code as asked:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestFile {
 public static void main(String str[]){
    List<Object> al = Arrays.asList("ABC", "XYZ");
}
```

Erro log:
`Error:(58, 42) java: incompatible types:java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>`

Java version 12,System windows 10 and IDE intelij

Comment: It doesn't look like this code alone will cause that error. Please show a [mcve] and the trace of the error. If you try to store `al` in an `ArrayList` variable, I can see you getting that error from that, but that's not caused by this code.

Comment: I tried only minimal this much code in a separate program and then to facing same error.

Comment: Again, show a [mcve] and the full error with trace.

Comment: Can you provide exact Java version and OS?

Comment: Does `List<String> al = Arrays.asList("ABC", "XYZ");` work? Why would you want to use `List<Object>` instead?

Comment: @Pshemo no that won't help as I am trying to use an external library which accepts List<Object>, I tried Passing List<String> but didn't work.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have provided the code and error log. Please check if it explains better. Thanks for help

Comment: @user85421 check the update. I have added a small part of the code that produces the error.

Comment: exactly, it says something very different, like `List<String>` cannot be converted to `List<Object>` - no word about casting or `ArrayList`

Comment: @user85421  java: incompatible types:java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object> this is actually error. Any idea why its coming? it works fine in java 11

Comment: Try using `Arrays.<Object>asList("ABC", "XYZ");` instead.

Comment: or `Arrays.asList((Object) "ABC", "XYZ")` or Java 13 (original working fine for me with OpenJDK 13) - also working with OpenJDK 12 (but eclipse)

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @user85421 I deleted the project and reinstalled the java. Now it's running as expected. not sure what was the real cause.

Comment: @Manish - great question!  Q: Can you update your JDK to Java 13 (per user85421)?  Have you tried using `Arrays.<Object>asList("ABC", "XYZ")` (per Jon Skeet)?  Please update your post with the results.

Comment: @FoggyDay I think it was an issue with JDK n IDE. I was trying since morning so in the end I just reinstalled java-12 and it started working.

Comment: just curious if the type inference logic changed in JDK12?

Comment: I'm an Eclipse fan, myself ;)

Comment: This should work. But as a side note when you want to pass a `List<String>` to another code expecting a `List<Object>` and is not supposed to modify it, you can use `List<Object> listOfObject = Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfString);` The creates a thin wrapper which prevents modifications through the `List<Object>`, hence, the type change is safe, as every `String` is an `Object`.

Comment: The compiler is trying to convert a list of strings to a list of objects, but these are incompatible types. A list of strings can only contain strings, while a list of objects can contain any type of object. To fix the error, you can either change the type of the list to be a list of strings, or you can cast the strings to objects.   <br/> `List<Object> al = Arrays.asList((Object) "ABC", (Object) "XYZ");`